# Position of Nearest in sublist

Tags: nearest, list-manipulation

I want to get the position of nearest value or the position of the value in a certain range.
When I have the list, such as

```
list={{{200.2,10,20,8.1},{215.4,12,13,9}},{{105,11,23.2,6.5},{175,21,5.1,3},{214,23,18,4.1},{199,18,24.5,7.5}},{{209,8,11.1,3.4},{233,4.3,5,2},{188,21,30.2,9.1}}};
```

Question1: How to write the position of each sublist, whose first element is nearest to 213? I mean the position list of `{215.4,12,13,9}`,`{214,23,18,4.1}`, and `{209,8,11.1,3.4}`,

```
pos1={2,3,1}
```

or

```
pos2= {{1,2},{2,3},{3,1}}.
```

After extracting the position, I need to make a list of

```
list2={{215.4,12,13,9},{214,23,18,4.1},{209,8,11.1,3.4}}
```

If somebody know how to derive `pos1`(or `pos2`) and `list2`, please tell me. (Maybe my problem is that I cannot handle the sublist freely.)

Question2: How to write the position of each sublist, whose third element is between 17.5 and21? Though the problem is similar to Question1, but this time NOT Nearest, but in the certain range.

I want to get the position list of `{200.2, 10, 20, 8.1}` and `{214,23,18,4.1}`

```
pos3={1,3,NaN}
```

or

```
pos4={{1,1},{2,3},{3,NaN}}
```

Then I also want to get the `list3`,

```
list3={{200.2, 10, 20, 8.1},{214,23,18,4.1}}
```

How can I derive `pos3` (or `pos4`) and `list3`?

I'm also interested in how to write `list3` using the list of `pos3` (or `pos4`).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Q1.**

```
ClearAll[nFs]
nFs = Nearest[#[[All, 1]] -> "Index"] & /@ list;

Flatten @ Through @ nFs @ 213
```

> ```
>  {2, 3, 1}
> ```

```
MapIndexed[{#2[[1]], #} &] @ %
```

> ```
>  {{1, 2}, {2, 3}, {3, 1}}
> ```

```
Extract[list, %]
```

> ```
>  {{215.4, 12, 13, 9}, {214, 23, 18, 4.1}, {209, 8, 11.1, 3.4}}
> ```

**Q2.**

```
Flatten[Values /@ KeySelect[17.5 <= #[[3]] <= 21 &] /@ PositionIndex /@ list /.
   {} -> "NaN"]
```

> ```
> {1, 3, "NaN"}
> ```

```
MapIndexed[{#2[[1]], #} &] @ %
```

> ```
>  {{1, 1}, {2, 3}, {3, "NaN"}}
> ```

```
Extract[list, DeleteCases[{_, "NaN"}]@%]
```

> ```
>  {{200.2, 10, 20, 8.1}, {214, 23, 18, 4.1}}
> ```

Comment: Thank you so much to give me suggestions! Now I see I should learn about the usage of functions related to Index, such as "MapIndexed" and "Position Index". Also, thank you for editing my question in haste and telling me solution to not only current question but also to the previous one. The code above is very nice to understand the usage of @ and %, too, which I'm weak at. Thanks again!

Comment: @nancy, my pleasure. Thank you for the accept. And welcome to mma.se.

Comment: You are so kind! Thank you VERY much.

Comment: I wish I had known mma.se much earlier. I found this community just the day before yesterday, and until then, only I could do was to read book or Help page of Wolfram. People here are warm-hearted like you.

Answer (score 3):

```
(* Q1 - nearest first elements *)
nffirst = Nearest[#, DistanceFunction -> Function[{p, q}, Abs[First[p] - First[q]]]] & /@ list;
First[#[{213, 0, 0}]] & /@ nffirst

(* result: {{215.4, 12, 13, 9}, {214, 23, 18, 4.1}, {209, 8, 11.1, 3.4}} *)

(* Q2 - positions in the 3rd element *)
Flatten[Join[
   Position[#, x_ /; 17.5 <= x[[3]] <= 21, 1, Heads -> False] & /@ 
    list] /. {{} -> NaN}]

(* result: {1, 3, NaN} *)
(* you should probably replace NaN with something more sensible like {} or Missing[] *)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for telling me a nice answer. It's very easy to understand, even for experimentalists like me. I'm happy to know how to get the list I want with the functions I often use. I want to follow your answers for other questions to learn more.